# Turn on the screen by script-command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, monitor, xrandr

I'm looking for a solution to turn the screen on using a script. Brightness & Lock in System Settings are set so that the screen turns off when inactive for 5 minutes. I'm using an alarm clock application that executes every morning a script that is running Audacious with a certain playlist.

I would like to add to this script a command that will turn the screen of the laptop on.

Is it possible to make using a caffeine application or somehow else?

Comment: Hi V.Plagov, posted my answer. I noticed you never accepted an answer before, which could be because you never got a satisfying answer, but also because you might not be familiar with the fact that accepting an answer is the way to indicate an it works for you. (only) *if* the answer answers your question, please consider accepting it (tick the big V below the up/down arrows next to the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Switch on screen by command

To switch on your screen from cli, the tool to use is `xrandr`.

#### What to do

1. Run in a terminal window:

   ```
    xrandr
   ```
2. In the output, there is a string "connected". The first string of that line shows the screen name, looking like `LVDS-1` or `VGA-1` or something.
3. The command you need then to turn on the screen, if my screen would be `VGA-1`:

   ```
    xrandr --output VGA-1 --auto
   ```

You can test it with the command:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --off && sleep 5 && xrandr --output VGA-1 --auto
```

which should turn off the screen, and back on after five seconds.

#### Alternatively

If, for some reason, the command above does not work, alternatively use:

```
xset dpms force on
```

To test, run

```
xset dpms force off && sleep 5 && xset dpms force on
```

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive response. How can I include this command into the script? I want to run both Audacious and turn the screen on.

I tried this:

`#!/bin/bash
audacious /home/plagov/bin/scripts/alarm/morow.m3u && xrandr --output eDP1 --auto`

Audacious starts, but the screen still stays off.

Comment: @V.Plagov Simply put & between the two commands (on the same line). && will not run the second command until the first command has completed successfully :)

Comment: tried with both && and &, but the screen doesn't turn on. Run test command for 5 seconds from your first post - it worked.

Even tried to change order of the commands (turning screen on first and Audacious second). Same result... :(

Comment: @V.Plagov I see, does `xset dpms force on` do the job? (test with `xset dpms force off && sleep 5 && xset dpms force on`)

Comment: Well, `xset` command works a little better - mouse pointer appears, but the screen still stays off.

However, test works fine, as expected.

Comment: @V.Plagov if a simple mousemove or keystroke works, I will post plan C tonight: I will make xdotool simulate a mouse click. That will work for sure. (Am on mobile currently)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49887/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-v-plagov).